# Cordova Google OAuth 2.0 - error in getting token

Tags: android, cordova, oauth, google-plus, inappbrowser

I've been struggling for some times now to get user profile of Google+ using Google OAuth 2.0 authentication, that I access from InAppBrowser in Cordova. I have been able to get the response code from InAppBrowser. The problem occur when I want to get the authorization token using the response code, that I want to use it to access Google+ API. I don't know which URL should I use to get the token, and for the client_secret, I am using the one provided in Google Developers console's credential (Key for Android applications: API key).

Here is the code:

```
authorize: function(options) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
        response_type: 'code',
        client_id: options.client_id,
        redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
        scope: options.scope
    });

    var authWindow = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

    $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {
        var url = e.originalEvent.url;
        var code = app.getParameterByName(url, 'code').trim();
        var error = app.getParameterByName(url, 'error');

        if (code || error) {
            authWindow.close();

            if (code) {
                $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                    code: code,
                    client_id: options.client_id,
                    client_secret: options.client_secret,
                    redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                }).done(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).fail(function(response) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                });
            } else if (error) {
                deferred.reject({error: error});
            }
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

This request will always be caught as failed, with response message:
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18"}

Really need your help.

Thank you

Comment: quick guess, try to uninstall plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" and then add instead "cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist". Please not that is not a recommended solution, but if it fixes your issue, it would mean you have to configure properly security settings. What version of android are you testing with?

Comment: I'm using cordova v5.1.1 with android v4.0.2 installed. I've tried your suggestion just now, replacing the whitelist plugin with the legacy one. Unfortunately the result was just the same. The response still caught as failed.  So for the token url, should I use https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token to access instead? I've tried that one as well, but still failed. Is there any parameter that I put wrong for the request? The response error message also not clear enough for me to search on Google. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Is it about the Content-Security-Policy, as in cordova v5.1.1 using cordova-plugin-whitelist, it specified: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

Comment: Error message that I got using adb logcat: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to connect to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Thought that using cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist would disable all the CSP checking... well seems I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is in your latest comment. You define a default-src to self and don't define a connect-src, so your app is allowed to connect only to the current page.

You may define either * or accounts.google.com as connect-src:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *;">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com;">
```